# Gremlin: Sorting based on rating

Tags: gremlin

I have below scanario:

```
User1------------rated[rating:3.0]----------->product1[productId: 1]
User2------------rated[rating:2.0]----------->product1[productId: 1]


User3------------rated[rating:4.0]----------->product2[productId: 10]
User4------------rated[rating:1.0]----------->product2[productId: 10]
```

I have to sort `product` based on rating (calculated based on all `rating coming on product`). means product with high rating on top, then lower....like that.

How can I do that

Answer (score 1):

There are a number of ways to accomplish this.  Here's one approach that translates your problem to the standard TinkerPop toy graph (sorting vertices by "weight" property which is analogous to your "rating" property):

```
gremlin> g = TinkerGraphFactory.createTinkerGraph()
==>tinkergraph[vertices:6 edges:6]
gremlin> g.v(1).outE.transform{[v:it.inV.next(),weight:it.getProperty("weight")]}.sort{-it.weight}
==>{v=v[4], weight=1.0}
==>{v=v[2], weight=0.5}
==>{v=v[3], weight=0.4}
```

The above code basically traverses to the out edges of vertex with id=1.  It then applies a transform to each edge coming through the pipe, where the edge is converted to a `Map` that contains the incoming vertex for the edge and the "weight" property from the edge.  Then you can apply a groovy descending sort (signified by the minus) on the "weight" value in that `Map`.